# Imprimir resultado en php

Tags: php

buen día, agradezco mucho me puedan dar una mano, estoy tratando e imprimir el resultado de una consulta que solo me trae un resultado el cual quiero imprimir en una etiqueta h4. Es algo sencillo solo que no logro ver donde tengo el error.

este es mi códigp en php

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    $html = '';

    //$bloque = $_POST ['bloque'];
    $bloque = "001";
    $nave = "1";
    $cama = "5";
    $sql = "Select  variedad from siat.plano where bloque = '.$bloque.' and nave = '.$nave.' and cama = '.$cama.';";

    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $html .= '<h4 id="txt_Variedad">'.$row['variedad'].'</h4>';            
        }               
    }
    echo $html;     
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de esto?, te manda algún error?? cuál es el var_dump() de $query, etc

Comment: El error puede estar en tu sintaxis de SQL, si cuando creaste la base de datos, pusiste las filas con `INT`, entonces el problema es de tu PHP, pero si lo pusiste con `VARCHAR`, el problema sí es tu SQL (debes poner los valores entre comillas para que sea un string y SQL no arroje un error), intenta usar `$conexion->connect_errno` o `$conexion->error` para ver algún posible error.

Comment: @RodrigoRamírez muchas gracias, efectivamente era esas comillas para los varchar